# dont add rule for certain input field

Tags: php, html, forms

So I have input fields and when they are submitted, I check to see if their inputted text appears in an array:

```
<form method="post">
   <input type="text" name="1">
   <input type="text" name="2">
   <input type="text" name="3">
   <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit'] {

   $array = array('432423', '434', '3', '2', '213');

   $success = true;

   foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value) {
        if (!empty($value) && $key != "submit") {
            if (!in_array($value, $array)) {
                $success = false;
            }
        }
   }


   var_dump($success); 
   // TRUE if all contains, FLASE if any one doesn't contain

}

?>
```

But if I wanted a certain input field not to have to be checked against the array, how would I do this

Comment: you're already doing EXACTLY what you're asking about with the `$key != 'submit'`, so.... what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @MarcB it's not only the submit button i dont want to be checked. i want another input form not to be checked

Comment: so `$key != 'submit' && $key != 'whateverelse'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you probably want to check for another `$key != something`?

E.g.

```
if (!empty($value) && $key != "submit" && $key != "2") {
   ...
```

This would exclude the second input...

Comment: do i have to set the value for the input field?

Comment: @bob Ok, what is the issue? I don't get it then. Because I have addressed it and it does work.

Comment: so basically if an input field has the name "notme" i dont want it to be checked against the array

Comment: @bob That's exactly what I did. The `$key` is the name, right?

Comment: Sorry I updated it to `$key != "notme"` and it worked thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can gather all the names in an array just set name="names[]" for the wanted inputs and you will be able to access all the inputs as an array ($_POST['names'])

```
<form method="post" action="">
   <input type="text" name="names[]">
   <input type="text" name="names[]">
   <input type="text" name="names[]">
   <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

and loop through them like this

```
if (! empty($_POST['names']) ) {

$names = $_POST['names'];
   foreach ($names as $value) {
        if (!empty($value)) {
            if (!in_array($value, $array)) {
                $success = false;
            }
        }
   }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

use https://jqueryvalidation.org

```
<form id="my_form" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="a1">
   <input type="text" name="a2">
   <input type="text" name="a3">
   <input type="checkbox" name="chk1" id="chk1">
   <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#my_form").validate({
        rules: {
            "a1": {
                required: true
            },
            "a2": {
                required: true
            },
            "a3": {
                required: true
            }, 
            "chk1": {
                required: {
                    depends: function() {
                      return !$("#chk1").is(":checked");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: sorry i can't use jquery

Comment: so, why did you mark my answer as not useful since you didn't specify that you cannot use js in the first place ?

Comment: bob didn't tag the question with [jquery], so they don't want to use it. But you somehow supposed they would like to see the jquery approach. Who told you that?..